# Can't load `active_support/core_ext` in ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby

When I `require 'active_support/core_ext'`, then get a error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb:3:in `<module:NumberHelper>'
```

Of course I installed `activesupport` gem.

```
# gem list --local | grep activesupport
activesupport (4.2.0)
```

Should I install some other gems to use `active_support/core_ext`?

I'm using `ruby 2.1.5p273` in Ubuntu14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you're using bundler, try this diagnostic code to see what works:

```
require 'rubygems'        # You may be able to omit this line
require 'bundler/setup'   # You may be able to omit this line
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

Newer Ruby versions may be able skip `rubygems`, `setup`, and `core_ext`, and just use this:

```
require 'active_support'
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, `require 'active_support'` is all I needed before `require 'active_support/core_ext`. By the way, I could require the `active_support/core_ext` without requiring `active_support`. Is this recently changed?

Comment: As far as I know, using require core_ext (on its own) has been deprecated, and I presume you're seeing it's now phased out.